# Real analysis Question about Lebesgue-measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

I had a question about the following question.  I ended up getting that the answer was false for each of the examples, but I feel like I may have made a mistake.  Any help is appreciated.  The question is,

Let $E \subset [0, 1]$ be a Lebesgue-measurable set with $m(E) = 1/2.$  Which of the following sets are guaranteed to exist?

(a) a closed set $F \subset E$ with $\mu(F) = 1/4.$

(b) a closed set $F \subset E$ with $\mu(F) = 1/2.$

(c) a closed set $F \supset E$ with $\mu(F) = 1/2.$

(d) a closed set $F \supset E$ with $\mu(F) = 3/4.$

Comment: I'm positive d is false, and c is false.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by $\mu$ you meant $m$?

Only (a) is true.

(a) By regularity, there exists a closed set $C \subset E$ such that $m C > mE - \frac{1}{8}$, in particular, $m C > \frac{1}{4}$. Let $\phi(x) = \int_0^x 1_C dm$. $\phi$ is continuous, with $\phi(0) = 0$, and $\phi(1) = mC$. Hence there exists some $f \in [0,1]$ such that $\phi(f) = \frac{1}{4}$. Let $F = C \cap [0,f]$, then $mF = \phi(f) = \frac{1}{4}$.

(b) Let $E = (0,\frac{1}{2})$, and $F \subset E$ be closed. Since $0, \frac{1}{2} \notin E$, we have $0 < \inf F$, $\sup F < \frac{1}{2}$, and $F \subset [\inf F, \sup F]$, hence $m F < \frac{1}{2}$.

(c,d) Let $E = ([0,\frac{1}{2}] \cup \mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1]$. Then $mE = \frac{1}{2}$, but if $F$ is any closed set containing $E$, then since $\overline{E} = [0,1]$, we have $mF \ge 1$.